# Correct order of enlarge, color and bold

Tags: color, fontsize, bold

What is the right way to have a text enlarged, colored and bold? Non of the following works;

```
documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}

% I just write the likely relevant packages.
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}
\mdfdefinestyle{algos}{backgroundcolor=mygrey, linewidth = 1.95pt, frametitlerule=false, frametitlebackgroundcolor=myblue, %
hidealllines=true}

% All colors, perhaps is not the case to be written.
\definecolor{airforceblue}{rgb}{0.36, 0.54, 0.66}

\begin{document}

\large{\color{airforceblue} {\textbf{$N_L(k)$}}}
{\color{airforceblue} \textbf{\large $N_L(k)$}}
{\color{airforceblue} \large{\textbf{$N_L(k)$}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps {\large text} instead of \large{text} ?

Comment: Doesn't work again; {\color{airforceblue} \textbf{\large $N_{abc}$}}. Actually everything is ok except being *Bold*.

Comment: please provide complete document starting with `\documentclass{...}`, used packages and defined colors `\begin{document}` your test code `\end{document}`.

Comment: Incidentally, you should *not* load `color` and `colortbl` indepdently. Instead, run `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`. This will ensure maximal interoperability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `\textbf` for math-mode material. Use `\mathbf` instead; better yet, load the `bm` package and the `\bm` ("bold math") macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,bm}
\begin{document}
$N_{abc}$ vs.\ {\Large\color{blue}$\bm{N_{abc}}$}
\end{document}
```

I don't know how the color "airforceblue" is defined. That's why I used "blue" in the example above. I use `\Large` instead of `\large` to make the effect of changing the font size more visually prominent.

Comment: Yes for the color is ok. It works , thanks!

Comment: also work `\textcolor{blue}{\Large$\bm{N_{abc}}$}` ...

Comment: @Zarko - Indeed, `\color{<somecolor>}...` is a switch, whereas `\textcolor{<somecolor>}{...}` takes a second argument. Same as with `\bfseries` vs. `\textbf{...}` or `\itshape` vs. `\textit{...}`. :-)